# How to fix "'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" when trying to start PaperMC Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm running a PaperMC server as the title suggests, but whenever I try running the server via the batch file I get this error:

> 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

The text in the batch file is:

```
java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar paper.jar nogui
PAUSE
```

Help would be greatly appreciated and I can supply more information if needed.

Comment: @VTCer's, I don't really see this as a request for technical support for modded Minecraft.  Yes this is a non-vanilla server, but the issue isn't specific to a modded server/game crashes, abnormal behavior, or an error *specific to modded games/servers* (yes there is an error, but its not a modded game error).  If anything, this is more of a general computing question, but considering how tightly coupled Java and *Minecraft Java Edition* are, I thought this was a good fit for the site.  I can see this being a typical problem many users could run into when trying to start a Java server.

Comment: Personally, my viewpoint is that unless the question is actually specific to the game (and this question isn't because the fact that java is being used to run a game is tangential to the question) it belongs on Super User, not here. But I've had inconsistent at best results in the close vote queue trying to enforce that interpretation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about general computing, not gaming.

Comment: @pppery This question is likely to be closed at Super User. According to the [Super User help page](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), video game-related questions are off-topic there. I agree with `@TimmyJim that this isn't off-topic here in Arqade.

Comment: But this isn't a video-game-related question. It's a question about running non-gaming specific software (Java) that just happens to be used for a game when that last part is trivial.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like Java is either not installed on the machine, or it's not added to PATH - in other words, Windows can't find the Java executable.

If you type in a command prompt [`where`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/where) `java`, if Java is installed, you should get back a file path of where the Java executable is. Take note of this file path.  At this point you have two options:

1. Update your batch file to change directory (`cd`) to the path of where the Java executable is prior to calling `java`.
2. Add the path to your PATH environment variables, which makes the executable accessible from any path. [Java's website](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) has a guide on how to do this:

> 1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
> 2. Click the Advanced system settings link.
> 3. Click Environment Variables. In the section System Variables find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click Edit. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click New.
> 4. In the Edit System Variable (or New System Variable) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click OK. Close all remaining windows by clicking OK.
> 5. Reopen Command prompt window, and run your java code.

Comment: What do you mean by change directory in the batch file? It doesn't have a directory listed? Also what do I specify the value of PATH to?

Comment: @BitPika you set the path variable to the path to the Java executable (the path returned from the `where`) It should be something similiar to  "C:\Program Files\Java" where \Java is the folder containing the Java executable. By change directory, I mean literally that... batch files I believe execute from the directory they are ran from, thus you need to change the directory in order for the batch script to find the executable. It's probably easier to add Java to the PATH.

Comment: Would I be able to change the directory using:

cd "(path)"
java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar paper.jar nogui
PAUSE

Comment: @BitPika That sounds correct yes, assuming the `cd` part is on its own line.

Comment: I did "where java" and I don't know which path I am supposed to use. https://ibb.co/VHvQB5n (ImgBB)

Comment: Also do I replace the preexisting PATH that contains system32?

Comment: @BitPika you do not want to replace any existing PATH parameters.  You probably want to use the one found in the path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.3.1\bin`.  See this site for a guide on how to edit the PATH parameter: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/  You will want to modify the "Systems" PATH parameter.